# Create "duplicate copy" of github repository

Tags: git, github, repository, duplicates, clone

I see answers to similar questions and I'm sure I may just not be familiar enough with Git and Github terminology to know if they apply to my question. What I need to do is to clone an existing Github remote repository (a private repo under another person's username that I have contributor access to) and create a new private remote repo under my account. The existing repo user is going to make significant alterations to the repo, delete, and re-push, before they do that they want me to clone and create a duplicate so we can continue working from the repo under my user. I want to preserve the commit history with the repo if possible.

I've cloned locally but don't can't seem to figure out how to push it to a new remote that isn't origined to the original user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd have to have more details, but there's a good chance what you're trying to do is unnecessary.

It's quite possible the owner can accomplish their goals by creating a branch and making that branch look how they desire, possible replacing master with it, if that's the desired end goal. They can do that without destroying all the existing history.

Or, you may be able to fork the repository.  However, keep in mind that if they're going to completely rewrite history, it will likely make it difficult to integrate the work you're doing on the fork, assuming that's a goal.

You also can push the copy you have cloned by deleting the current remote `git remote rm origin` and creating a new one that points to a repository created under your account.  Here again though, if the original repository completely changes, it will be difficult to integrate any work done on your "copy."

Comment: I may be misunderstanding -- but I assumed if they delete or unrecognizably alter the upstream, that my fork/clone would be affected as well? Sounds like that assumption was incorrect.

Comment: They're only affected if you subsequently pull or fetch from them.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful, I was pretty much just fundamentally confused about how Git works.

Answer (score 3):

When using GitHub interface, the easiest way is to [fork a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/).

Alternatively, as suggested in the following [Duplicating a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/) article at GitHub, you can achieve repo duplication by following these shell commands:

1. Create a bare clone of the repository:

   ```
   git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
   ```
2. Mirror-push to the new repository:

   ```
   cd old-repository.git
   git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
   ```
3. Remove the temporary local repository you created in step 1:

   ```
   cd ..
   rm -rf old-repository.git
   ```

Comment: should be `cd old-repository`, not `cd old-repository.git`. You can't `cd` to a file. Same for `rm -rf`

Comment: @OleksandrNovik folders also can have dots in their name, `something.git` doesn't mean it's a file. Even going further, every local Git repo has a folder named `.git`.

Answer (score 2):

Would you not be able to accomplish what you're trying to do by [forking](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) the repository on github and then cloning and working on that?

That also retains a relationship between the two repositories and allows you the option, at a later date, of merging their changes into your repo or vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks it does work this way, I was totally misunderstanding the relation to the upstream copy.